# FindViewById from LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

I have a code for inflate layout:

```
mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

addNewMed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addNewMed.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MedicationAdd.this, R.anim.rotate_complete));
        v = LayoutInflater.from(MedicationAdd.this).inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, null);
        mesurement = v.findViewById(R.id.mesurement);
        mainLayout.addView(v);
    }
});
```

And when I would to find my spinner `mesurement` from `medication_poles` I have a null-error

medication_poles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/medPole"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Время приема"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Препарат"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Дозировка"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mesurement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

**How to find object from inflating layout?**

Comment: post `res/layout/medication_poles.xml`

Comment: see question, refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using view which was passed to you in onClick method. that v(view) has only that much scope so you can't use that view object out of that method.
v(view object) might give you crash because it may not be able to cast to view class from button class.

Try below code.

```
//define this object for class level access
View newView;

mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

addNewMed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
addNewMed.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MedicationAdd.this, R.anim.rotate_complete));
            newView = LayoutInflater.from(MedicationAdd.this).inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, null);
mesurement = newView.findViewById(R.id.mesurement);
            mainLayout.addView(newView);
        }
    });

    if(newView != null)
        // do findviewbyid here for other views
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you'r not adding inflated view to a container.
So replace:

```
 v = LayoutInflater.from(MedicationAdd.this).inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, null)
```

with:

```
 v = LayoutInflater.from(MedicationAdd.this).inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, mainView,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
addNewMed.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MedicationAdd.this,R.anim.rotate_complete));        
another_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, null);
mesurement = another_view.findViewById(R.id.mesurement);
mainLayout.addView(another_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define New View object with different name like 'view' , v is onClick instance parameter and you should use another one .

try this :

```
addNewMed.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MedicationAdd.this, R.anim.rotate_complete));
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(MedicationAdd.this).inflate(R.layout.medication_poles, null);
mesurement = view.findViewById(R.id.mesurement);
            mainLayout.addView(view);
```